# Monthly Active Users on HERE API

Tags: here-api

I am looking at the pricing page for HERE API (https://developer.here.com/pricing) and I am a bit confused about the monthly active user limit.

What exactly does a limit of 5k monthly active users on HERE API mean? And what happens if you exceed this limit?

Answer (score 2):

A Monthly Active User (MAU) represents an active customer app installation on a device that uses any one of the following HERE Location Services, HERE SDKs, HERE Live Sense SDK or HERE Data Layers in a given billing month. If you have more than 5,000 monthly active users (MAUs) for your application, [contact us](https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you) for a plan tailored to your needs.

Also you can check out these [knowledge base](https://knowledge.here.com/csm_kb?id=public_kb_csm_details&number=KB0016403) for your reference.

Comment: Does the MAU apply to the Search API usage?